# SSH tectia, how to run batch commands?

Tags: windows, ssh, cmd

I have tectia ssh server in a windows environment. 
When I use `sftpg3 -B cmd.txt username@host` that works fine. The only problem is that it doesnt let me execute files remotely, it only lets me move files. It reads the commands from cmd.txt but since I cant execute anything it ignores the commands.

Well when I do the same thing but use sshg3, it doesnt recognize the -B flag at all.

`SSHG3 -B cmd.txt username@host`

> cmd.txt' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
>   operable program or batch file.

I've tried putting -B "cmd.txt"

I tried just putting the cmd.txt contents in the same script instead of housing them in cmd.txt and getting rid of `-B`, but it doesnt run them that way either.

The docs dont have much to go off of. All it says is use -B for batch processing.

Contents of cmd.txt:

`D:
cd Library
cd Backup
parseLibrary.cmd
exit`

Trying to sshg3 into a host, navigate to a path and run a batch file on that host. 
Any ideas?

> -B, --batch-mode
>   Uses batch mode. Fails authentication if it requires user interaction on the terminal.
>
> Using batch mode requires that you have previously saved the server host key on the client and set up a non-interactive method for user authentication (for example, host-based authentication or public-key authentication without a passphrase).

It does use public key authentication, there is no user interaction needed on the terminal.

Noticed this on the docs for sftpg3

> -B [ - | batch_file ]
>
> The -B - option enables reading from the standard input. This option is useful when you want to launch processes with sftpg3 and redirect the stdin pipes.
>
> By defining the name of a batch_file as an attribute, you can execute SFTP commands from the given file in batch mode. The file can contain any allowed SFTP commands. For a description of the commands, see the section called “Commands”.
>
> Using batch mode requires that you have previously saved the server host key on the client and set up a non-interactive method for user authentication (for example, host-based authentication or public-key authentication without a passphrase).

I'm guessing batch file is different than batch mode?

*I figured it out. You have to use the -B flag for every command you want to execute.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. You have to use the -B flag for every command you want to execute.
`sshg3 user@host -B dir -B ipconfig -B etc.cmd`